# How to create a smooth "Ken Burns" style animation using "transform" instead of "object-position" in CSS? (demo included)

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I'm attempting to create a "Ken Burns" style animation using CSS "transform" properties. Currently, I'm using "object-position" to control the animation, but I'm encountering issues with the smoothness of the movement.

I would like to know if anyone can help me create a smoother animation using only CSS transform properties like "translate" or "scale".

Additionally, I have created a demo showcasing my current implementation (or, if you prefer, on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/schererm/pen/ExOPgdq)):

```css
body {
    display: flex;
}
.image-container {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.object-position .image-container img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    animation: kenBurns-object-position 20s linear infinite;
    object-fit: cover;
}
.transform .image-container img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    animation: kenBurns-tranform 20s linear infinite;
    object-fit: cover;
}
@-webkit-keyframes kenBurns-object-position {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1.2);
        object-position: left top;
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1.0);
        object-position: center;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes kenBurns-tranform {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1.2) translate(-50px,0px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1.0) translate(0px,0px);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="object-position">
    <h1>Animation using "object-position"</h1>
    <label>image ratio: 1x1</label>
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/featured/500x500">
    </div>
    <label>image ratio: 2x1</label>
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/featured/1000x500">
    </div>
    <label>image ratio: 1x2</label>
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/featured/500x1000">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="transform">
    <h1>Animation using "transform"</h1>
    <label>image ratio: 1x1</label>
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/featured/500x500">
    </div>
    <label>image ratio: 2x1</label>
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/featured/1000x500">
    </div>
    <label>image ratio: 1x2</label>
    <div class="image-container">
        <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/featured/500x1000">
    </div>
</div>
```

Important points to consider:

- I need the animation to work seamlessly with images of various aspect ratios, including horizontal, vertical, and square images. In the demo I provided on CodePen, I have included examples of all three formats to illustrate this.
- The final result I expect should be exactly what is achieved using "object-fit". The only problem is the smoothness of the animation, which becomes completely jerky, especially for longer durations (I intend to use animations between 40 and 60 seconds).

Thank you in advance for your attention and assistance. I would be truly grateful if anyone could help me with this matter.

Comment: What is a "Ken Burns" style of animation?

Comment: Hi @ScottMarcus. It's an effect that's often used in video editing using panning and zoom to show static images... But I just put it here to relate... I believe that seeing the demo I put there on CodePen will make you better understand the type of animation I'm looking for... Thanks!

Comment: The two colmns in your codepen are incorrectly labelled. It wold be useful for future readers if you were to put a working snippet direct into your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth fixed! I will also be updating my question to include a working snippet. Thanks!

Comment: You mean something like this? https://codepen.io/gitlango/pen/KKrVaMz

Comment: @PauloFernando your answer does not achieve the desired effect (to look like the (object-fit option)...

When animating the images, they have a white background appearing, and in addition, it animates all images equally, regardless of whether they are vertical or horizontal...

Answer (score 0):

Well... I managed to achieve the goal I wanted, but I think I might overengineer it a little bit...

I would still appreciate it if anyonde could have a look at the code below to improve it or at least simplify it.

Basically, I'm parsing the image with javascript and creating a class to tell if it's a landscape, portrait or square image. Also, I collect the dimensions of the image and save it as a variable to use in animation calculations...

One point that is still not 100% correct is the animation when it reaches the top or bottom of vertical images, or the right and left of horizontal images. In this case, due to the scale effect, it ends up not touching the edge of the image, but I decided to keep it that way to avoid even more calculations and complexity in this function...

```js
function analyzeImages() {
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('.item-image');

    images.forEach(function(image) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = image.src;

        img.addEventListener('load', function() {
        var width = img.naturalWidth;
        var height = img.naturalHeight;
        var aspectRatio = width / height;
        var imageClass = '';
        var largeSize = '';
        var smallSize = '';

        if (aspectRatio > 1) {
            imageClass = 'landscape';
            largeSize = width + 'px';
            smallSize = height;
        } else if (aspectRatio < 1) {
            imageClass = 'portrait';
            largeSize = height + 'px';
            smallSize = width;
        } else {
            imageClass = 'square';
            largeSize = width + 'px';
            smallSize = height + 'px';
        }

        image.classList.add(imageClass);
        image.style.setProperty('--large-size', largeSize);
        image.style.setProperty('--small-size', smallSize);
        });
    });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
analyzeImages();
});
```

```css
body {
        display: flex;
        margin: 100px;
    }
    .image-container {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        overflow: hidden;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
    .item-image.square {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        animation: kenBurns-square 30s linear infinite;
    }
    .item-image.landscape {
        height: 200px;
        animation: kenBurns-landscape 30s linear infinite;
    }
    .item-image.portrait {
        width: 200px;
        animation: kenBurns-portrait 30s linear infinite;
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes kenBurns-square {
        0% {
            transform: scale(1.3);
        }
        33% {
            transform: scale(1.0);
        }
        66% {
            transform: scale(1.0);
        }
        100% {
            transform: scale(1.3);
        }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes kenBurns-portrait {
        0% {
            transform: translateY(calc((var(--large-size) / (var(--small-size) / 200) - 200px) / -2)); /* center */
        }
        10% {
            transform: translateY(calc((var(--large-size) / (var(--small-size) / 200) - 200px) / -2)); /* center */
        }
        20% {
            transform: scale(1.0) translateY(0px); /* top */
        }
        40% {
            transform: scale(1.3) translateY(calc((var(--large-size) / (var(--small-size) / 200) - 200px) * -1)); /* bottom */
        }
        60% {
            transform: scale(1.3) translateY(0px); /* top */
        }
        80% {
            transform: scale(1.0) translateY(calc((var(--large-size) / (var(--small-size) / 200) - 200px) * -1)); /* bottom */
        }
        90% {
            transform: translateY(calc((var(--large-size) / (var(--small-size) / 200) - 200px) / -2)); /* center */
        }
        100% {
            transform: translateY(calc((var(--large-size) / (var(--small-size) / 200) - 200px) / -2)); /* center */
        }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes kenBurns-landscape {
        0% {
            transform: translateX(calc((var(--large-size) / (var(--small-size) / 200) - 200px) / -2)); /* center */
        }
        10% {
            transform: translateX(calc((var(--large-size) / (var(--small-size) / 200) - 200px) / -2)); /* center */
        }
        20% {
            transform: scale(1.0) translateX(0px); /* left */
        }
        40% {
            transform: scale(1.3) translateX(calc((var(--large-size) / (var(--small-size) / 200) - 200px) * -1)); /* right */
        }
        60% {
            transform: scale(1.3) translateX(0px); /* left */
        }
        80% {
            transform: scale(1.0) translateX(calc((var(--large-size) / (var(--small-size) / 200) - 200px) * -1)); /* right */
        }
        90% {
            transform: translateX(calc((var(--large-size) / (var(--small-size) / 200) - 200px) / -2)); /* center */
        }
        100% {
            transform: translateX(calc((var(--large-size) / (var(--small-size) / 200) - 200px) / -2)); /* center */
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
    <img class="item-image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/featured/500x500">
</div>
<div class="image-container">
    <img class="item-image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/featured/500x1000">
</div>
<div class="image-container">
    <img class="item-image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/featured/1000x500">
</div>
```